# Арифметические операции с экспоненциальными числами и числами с плавающей точкой

Tags: c++, числа, арифметика

Почему данный код считается не правильно и как решить данную проблемы ?

```
double a = -1.30766e-07;
double b = -1.73205;
std::cout << "a + b" <<   b + a << std::endl;
```

Вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно выводиться: -1.73205 - 0,0130766 = -1,7451266

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что 1.30766e-07 совсем не 0,0130766, а в 100 000 (сто тысяч) раз меньше.

Comment: А почему в консоль выводится не все число ?

Comment: Возможные причины: или по умолчанию выводится только до пятого или шестого знака после запятой. Или не хватает диапазона представления - если к большому числу с плавающей точкой прибавить маленькое, то большое число не изменится, потому что для представления не хватает бит. Для аналогии: если у нас для числа отведено только 5 знаков (и десятичная точка), то прибавляя к 12345 0.002 мы получим все равно 12345, потому что 12345.002 не вмещается в 5 знаков.